# NGINX Mulitple SSL certificates with one ip, different roots and domains

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx with two domains, each with a different ssl certificate and a different root location. 
The following code shows two times the exact same thing. 
domain1.com should go to /home/ubuntu/web/html/domain1 and should use  this: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem certificate. domain2.com should go to /home/ubuntu/web/html/domain2 and use this  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem certificate.

I tried the following:

```
server {  
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.domain1.com;
    return       301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  domain1.com;
    return       301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";

    root /home/ubuntu/web/html/domain1;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain1.com, www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }


    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE "developer";
    }

}


server {  
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.domain2.com;
    return       301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  domain2.com;
    return       301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";

    root /home/ubuntu/web/html/domain2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain2.com, www.domain2.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }


    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE "developer";
    }

}
```

It turns out that always one server block is chosen as default and also used for the the other domain.

Also adding an extra default server doesn't work.

Comment: Have you enabled SNI? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: The `server_name` directive should not have `,` separators. Just use spaces.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!